# Error Updating Page: Value cannot be null (Value given: null) TAAL[BLAME_file]

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I'm having a little bit of trouble. It seems that Facebook can't reach my website. So I get this error message under the Facebook comment box, and also I'm not able to like anything on my website.

First I got this error:

> Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed
>   Error Scraping Page: Bad Response Code

Now I get this error:

> Error Updating Page:
>   Value cannot be null (Value given: null) TAAL[BLAME_file]

None of my links works, testing:

1. http://iseeahappyface.com/having-a-rough-day-at-work
2. http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fiseeahappyface.com%2Fhaving-a-rough-day-at-work

Scraped URL: See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL shows me

> "Document returned no data"

**edit**
I've made a new .html page with just the code for Facebook commentbox. I got the same error.

**edit 2**
I've cleared my .htaccess, still the same error.

**edit 3** 
I have another domain at the web host, Facebook can't reach that website either I'd just noticed. My control panel is Parallels® H-Sphere. Is there anything I can check there? I will contact my webhost.

Comment: it seems that facebook is experiencing some problem. I'm currently using the facebook object debugger tool which respond the same error

Comment: I've been seeing this on my website now.  Did you ever get it resolved?

Comment: Comment from Yaraslau Kurmyza: Possible fix: tag is missing namespace attribute: xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/"

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc - Thanks for reply, did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I can see your page and it appears that Facebook is able to lint it:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fiseeahappyface.com%2Fhaving-a-rough-day-at-work

However, you still have a few warnings to fix.

```
**Like Button Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
Inferred Property:  fb:admins and fb:app_id missing. fb:admins or fb:app_id is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.
Inferred Property:  og:title missing. og:title meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.
Inferred Property:  og:type missing. og:type meta tag is necessary for Facebook to render a News Feed story that generates a high clickthrough rate.
**Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed**
Inferred Property:  The og:url property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:title property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
Inferred Property:  The og:locale property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.
```